# Changing the format of WMIC result

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using below command to get system memory in Output.txt file:

```
wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory > Output.txt
```

memory is coming in Output.txt file in below format:

```
FreePhysicalMemory  TotalVisibleMemorySize  
828556                   2061560
```

But i want, it should come like:

```
FreePhysicalMemory=      828556   
TotalVisibleMemorySize=  2061560
```

I tried some changes in command but not getting the output in required format and don't want to use **systeminfo** command as it takes time.

**EDIT1:**

Using both the below commands i am getting following output, but i want to add a single space after those equal signs(=)...:)

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist > Output.txt

wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Wmiclivalueformat > Output.txt
```

**Output.txt:**

```
FreePhysicalMemory=851528
TotalVisibleMemorySize=2061560
```

I am trying with below but not working..

```
For /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%A in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist') do 
echo %%A %%B > Output.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [here](http://ss64.com/nt/wmicstylesheets.html).
 What is closest to what you want shoud be:

```
wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize,FreePhysicalMemory /Format:Wmiclitableformatnosys
```

But better test them all , or define your own.

Comment: Please see **EDIT1** in question.and how i can define my own format..?...:)

Comment: what about `Wmiclitableformat` . may be didn't the correct one to you

Comment: using **Wmiclitableformat** output is coming in previous format not in required format..:)

Comment: @npocmaka..is it possible to simply add a space after '=' sign in **EDIT1** output..? I am trying with below but its not working for me.

`For /F "tokens=1 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist ) do 
@echo %a %b`

Comment: `For /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %a in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory^,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Format:Textvaluelist' ) do @if "%b" neq ""  @echo %a %b`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not much of an answer as it's not DOS based,
But why don't you use a powershell script?

```
 $test = gwmi win32_OperatingSystem
 "TotalVisibleMemorySize = " + $test.TotalVisibleMemorySize
 "FreePhysicalMemory = " + $test.FreePhysicalMemory
```

Also check out
[Why is FreePhysicalMemory giving an incorrect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308728/why-is-freephysicalmemory-giving-an-incorrect-value)

Comment: Angus..m using Windows xp..that's why preferring batch..thanks for valuable point..:)